# How do I amend these iptables rules so that they bind HTTP traffic to my VPN connection?

Tags: iptables, vpn

I have followed *[this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/622099/477263)* to set up a VPN service to send the data to/from `transmission-daemon` from my device running Debian.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Print environment variables for transmission's benefit
printenv > /etc/openvpn/myprovider/vpn.env


# Set up VPN routes
ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway dev $dev table 10

ip rule add from $ifconfig_local/32 table 10
ip rule add to $route_vpn_gateway/32 table 10

ip route flush cache


# Add firewall rules
iptables -A INPUT -i $dev -p udp --dport 24328 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $dev -p tcp --dport 24328 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o $dev -p udp --sport 24328 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $dev -p tcp --sport 24328 -j ACCEPT
```

I have used this *[TorGuard IP test torrent](https://torguard.net/checkmytorrentipaddress.php)* to see which IP address I am connecting from. The TorGuard torrent shows the correct VPN IP address.

However, when using a web browser and checking my IP address with an online IP lookup service, my actual "home" IP address is displayed.

The way I understand these `iptables` settings, is that they are set up to only allow VPN traffic directed to the Transmission port (24328), and drop all other traffic. If so, that traffic seems to be run through the normal internet connection. Is this interpretation correct?

Is there a way to amend these rules so that also ordinary browser traffic (HTTP) traffic binds to the VPN connection, while leaving other services/ports as they were?

I am using `PhantomJS` as my browser, and I think it's possible to set its preferred port to something else than the default.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am using `PhantomJS` but it's the same with `Epiphany`. I didn't think WebRTC was a problem with Linux but it might be?

Comment: Sorry, deleted comment when I read PhantomJS. PhantomJS claims to support WebRTC. Try the page with lynx for debugging the problem.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't think it's WebRTC. Looking up my IP via `Lynx` still gives my home IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those firewall rules ordinarily suggest that traffic is otherwise blocked, and they only serve to allow traffic to and from the given port. Since apparently all traffic is allowed by policy, these rules add nothing to it.

Next, the second routing rule likewise doesn't seem to be of much use, since the `$dev` device already would have the `$route_vpn_gateway` IP address, and therefore its traffic would already be routed to it.

The first routing rule is the one that should "do the work" of routing all traffic (not otherwise routed) from `$ifconfig_local` through `$dev`. This would require `$ifconfig_local` to be `127.0.0.1`, since that's where local traffic emanates. Since not all traffic goes through the VPN, it seems like `$ifconfig_local` is something else than `127.0.0.1`.

You can use the command `iptables-save` to review the iptables settings, and the command `ip route list` to review the routing.